# Add white space after every integer in a file using java

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write a code, which takes a file as input and outputs a file with white spaces after every integer if there isn't one.

Example:

`Input file contains: 3 0001
 Output file should be: 3 0 0 0 1`

The problem is, 0001 is detected as 1 and I get my output as

`3 1`

The below is the first code I tried

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputPath));
ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) integerArrayList.add(scanner.nextInt());
System.out.println(integerArrayList.toString());
scanner.close();
```

Output - `[3, 1]`

Tried reading as character

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(inputPath));
ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (fin.available() > 0) integerArrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(fin.read()));
System.out.println(integerArrayList.toString());
fin.close();
```

Now the output is - `[51, 32, 48, 48, 48, 49]`

Comment: Would you like to post your code?

Comment: i got really frustrated and closed it without saving! :/

Comment: So write it again, this time thinking carefully about what you are doing. What you are looking for are not integers, it's digit characters.

Comment: just added a small code, im reading the file and entering the integers in an arraylist, is there any way to detect the leading zeros?

Comment: Don't store a list of `Integer`. For `Integer` all leading zero will be discarded. For example `000001`, `0000000000001` and `1` will be treated as `1` (because `Integer` is really just a simple integer). Try to use `String` instead (which actually stores a sequence of `char`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and read the comment carefully.

```
Scanner inp=new Scanner(new File(inputPath));
ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//looking for next string
while(inp.hasNext()){
   String my_string=inp.next();//taking the string
   for(int i=0;i<my_string.length();i++){//adding every character of string
    try {//if a integer found add to list
        integerArrayList.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(my_string.charAt(i))));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          //exception occurs if an integer not found and do nothing 
        }
   }
}

//printing values and here you can use your code to write in another file but use a space(" ") after every integer to get your desired output
for(int i=0;i<integerArrayList.size();i++){
   System.out.print(integerArrayList.get(i)+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Except reading and writing files, I have tried to implement the logic you require. Hope this will help you!

Try this:

```
public class SpaceLogic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String chars = "3 0001";
      char[] charArray = chars.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toCharArray();
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for (char ch : charArray) {
        builder.append(ch).append(" ");
      }
      System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to read it into a String instead of an Integer. If you want to make certain it is an Integer, only check if the String is an Integer:

```
String someString=readInputLine(); // Your input instructions
String[] someStringArray=someString.split("");

for(int i=0;i<someStringArray.length;i++) {
try {
   Integer intVal=new Integer(someStringArray[i]);
   yourwritefunction(intVal);
} catch(Exception exp) { System.out.println("Not an integer, skipping write"); }
}
```